# Why this program can cause memory Leak?

Tags: java

Well , i was going through Memory Leaks in Java .

I saw this simple below program where the author says that 
Memory Leaks are possible with this below program

But could please tell me whats wrong with this program and why it can 
produce a Memory Leak ??

```
package com.code.revisited.memoryleaks;


public class StackTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>(10000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            s.push(i);
        }

        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            s.pop();
        }

        while(true){
            //do something
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It might be because the stack will still take some place but that's not really a "leak".

Comment: This isn't a memory leak. I guess ideally the `Stack` would go into a scope where it can be GC'd when you are done with it but this isn't a "leak".

Comment: If you are referring to http://coderevisited.com/memory-leaks-in-java/ , then leak is not in this example, but in `Stack.pop`. This part is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends how the stack is implemented.

If this is Java's stack (java.util.Stack), then it should not happen. The underlying array is dynamic and may have unused slots, but they are explicitly set to null when popping items.

I guess that the stack in your example is not the standard one; It's probably a part of the example, and it illustrates this kind of memory leak. For example, if the pop() method decreases the underlying array index, but doesn't set the array item to null, then the code above should leave 1000 live objects in the heap, although they are probably not needed anymore by the program.

-- Edit --

Did you take the example from http://coderevisited.com/memory-leaks-in-java/?
If so, note that it also includes a stack implementation, just as I suspected.

Comment: yes , i took example from there , but i want to produce memory leak .

Comment: @Kiran: Assuming that you rely on an array arr, and your current top index is denoted by j,your pop method should probably do the following: 1) Check whether the stack isn't empty 2)Save a reference with value arr[j] 3) Assign null to arr[j] 4) return the reference

Answer (score 1):

`pop` method is removing `Integer` objects from the `Stack`. But Integer objects are not de-referenced; this means that they will occupy memory.

**Update**:

This point is explained in `Item 6 of Effective Java` : **Eliminate obsolete object references**

`If a stack grows and then shrinks, the objects
that were popped off the stack will not be garbage collected, even if the program
using the stack has no more references to them. This is because the stack maintains
obsolete references to these objects. An obsolete reference is simply a reference
that will never be dereferenced again.`

The fix for this sort of problem is simple: null out references or remove object from Stack once they become obsolete. In given case pop method will decrement the top reference.

Comment: Are you referring to the first 256 ones ? Or what ?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense as the Java doc says it is removing the Integer from the top of the stack. So dereferencing is not really necessary. But I have never used `Stack`, so please elaborate so I can understand :)

Comment: I thought the same way as Andy , why dereferencing  required ??

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to make any sense. Why was it upvoted ?